callback data from sendMessage is true
I have a script that should get a value from the backgroud, basically it returns an item, but also for some reason it returns true when the function is called again.
In a background script item always object or undefined. How it got true in response is a mystery to me
market.js
async function renderMarketItem(item) {
  //parsers name, type and quality of item
  let market_item = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (chrome.runtime?.id) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        action: "getMarketItem",
        name: formatData(type, name, quality)
      }, (item) => {
        resolve(item);
      })
    } else resolve(undefined);
  });
  //another logic
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action == 'updateConfig') {
    $('.items-grid').children().each(function() {
      renderMarketItem($(this));
    })
  }
});

/*for example*/
$('.items-grid').children().each(function() {
  renderMarketItem($(this));
})

background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
   if (message.action == 'getMarketItem') {
        sendResponse(getMarketItem(message));
    }
    if (message.action == 'updateConfig') {
        updateConfig(message, sender, sendResponse);
    }

});
const updateConfig = (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    const {data} = message;
    getTabs((tabs) => {
        tabs.forEach((tab) => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: 'updateConfig', data });
        });
    });
}
let getTabs = (callback = ()=>{}) => {
       chrome.tabs.query({ url: /*siteUrl*/ }, (tabs) => {
          callback(tabs);
       });
}
const getMarketItem = (message) => {
    
    let targetName = message.name;
    let item;
    if (targetName) item = items.find(item => item.market_hash_name.trim() == targetName.trim());
    return item;
}

I did function async with return true and it didn't work

What's the point of the market_item variable? You never use it.

In Manifest V3, chrome.runtime.sendMessage() returns a Promise, so you don't need to use new Promise() and a callback argument. But you never await the call to renderMarketItem(), so why are you returning a promise in the first place?

For the example I have shortened the code and left the main thing, at the bottom under market_item I wrote that there is a different logic there

Let's say I have 800 elements that need to be processed and I need them to do it in parallel, i.e. not waiting for each other.

the value that the callback receives is the response object sent by the message handler. Your onMessage listener doesn't handle action: "getMarketItem", what response are you expecting?

   if (message.action == 'getMarketItem') {
        sendResponse(getMarketItem(message));
    }
}); ```

in background.js

Oops, missed that in the second code block.

If you call renderMarketItem not in chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener, everything works fine, the problem is exactly with working in the handler


true is probably from an old version of the code. Reload the extension in chrome://extensions and reload the tab. 2) Your setTimeout listener is not related to the main code because it receives from chrome.tabs.sendMessage, which you didn't show.


1)I always reload the extension after a change in the code
2) setTimeout is just a crutch that sometimes doesn't work, so no need to pay attention to it

Problem was in my popup react app
useEffect(() => {
    const handleMessage = async (message: any, sender: any, sendResponse: () => void) => {
      if (message.action === 'getConfig' && message.data) setConfig(message.data);
      return true;
    };

    runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);

    runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'needConfig' });
    return () => {
      runtime.onMessage.removeListener(handleMessage);
    };
  }, []);

This listener interrupted the listener from the content script and when the popup was opened it returned true.
I removed the listener and used the one-time request pattern where the response is returned by sendMessage:
useEffect(() => {
    const getConfig = async() => {
      let cfg = await runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'getConfig'});
      console.log(cfg);
      setConfig(cfg);
    }
    getConfig();
  }, []);

